# python class with mixed @classmethod and methods

Tags: python

Hi I'm developing a class in a project with different collaborators. I've been able to implement the class with different method and all is working properly. Basically my present situation is the following

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c  

    def one(self,**kwargs):
        d = self.two()
        e = self.three()
        # make something using a an b like 
        return 2*d + 3*e

    def two(self,**kwargs):
        # this uses a for example 
        return self.a*2 + self.b**self.c
    def three(self, **kwargs):
        # this uses b and c
        return self.b/self.c - self.a/3
```

These are clearly examples and there are more complicated stuff going on. The problem is that this class can be called only through an instance

```
[1]: x=MyClass(a,b,c)
[2]: y=x.one()
```

The class is inserted in a larger project and the other collaborators would like to call one without the istance directly as

```
[1]: y = MyClass.one(a,b,c)
[2]: z = MyClass.two(a,b,c)
[3]: x = MyClass.three(a,b,c)
```

I know that I can obtain this by using decorators, like @classmethod. For example for one I could do like

```
@classmethod
def one(cls, a, b, c):
    d = self.two()
    e = self.three()
    cos(2*d+3*e)
```

but this actually don't work because it raises an error as self is not defined. My problem is that I do not understand how a @classmethod can call another method pertaining in the same class if I did not make an instance. BTW I'm working on python 2.7
Thanks for any clue. I've tried to search on the various @classmethod question but did not find the answer (or maybe I did not understand it)

Comment: *"I do not understand how a @classmethod can call another method pertaining in the same class"* - by accessing it via `cls`. `self` isn't part of a class method (as you can see from the signature...), you have access to the *class*, not an *instance*.

Comment: If you call it without an instance, where do you expect `a`, `b`, and `c` to come from?

Comment: you are right I know. Sorry if the question was too simple and for the misspelling

Comment: Will you have one, only one instance of `MyClass` in your application?

Comment: No, in principle I can call MyClass different times, (with different values of a,b and c)

Comment: How will your class methods know which instance should be in charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You renamed the parameter into `cls`, so you have to change `self` in the function body into `cls`, too. The names `self` and `cls` are just normal identifiers, a convention, unlike e.g. C++'s `this`.

```
@classmethod
def one(cls, a, b, c):
    d = cls.two()
    e = cls.three()
    cos(2*d+3*e)
```

works the same as

```
@classmethod
def one(we_need_more_unicorns, a, b, c):
    d = we_need_more_unicorns.two()
    e = we_need_more_unicorns.three()
    cos(2*d+3*e)
```

Or a more reasonable identifer like `Cls` (with an uppercase C to denote that it is a class), which is seen sometimes, too.